# Problems with uploading pictures to WordPress

Tags: uploads

When trying to upload pictures to WordPress I face big problems. Sometimes it does not work at all and sometimes I need to try several times. Some pictures I even never managed to upload.

I tried uploading the pictures

- With different browsers (Firefox, Edge, Chrome)
- With the WordPress-Uploader drag-and-drop or selecting the pictures and also with the Browser-Uploader. With the Uploader it just does not continue to the next picture and stays with 100%. With the Browser-Uploader after a while there’s a error saying that the page could not be loaded.
- Deactivating all my plug-ins and do the upper steps again

I also tried to manually upload one picture to the database directly, accessing it from my hosts’ website. It didn’t show up in the Media-Overview.

The pictures are 500KB to 1.2MB, 1500x1000 pixel, 70 to 100dpi, jpg-format.

This is really annoying.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Should I try a new Installation of WordPress? Might there be a problem with my host and should I contact them?

I’m using the newest version of WordPress (atm 5.9.2) and the Plug-ins.

Comment: which plugin are you referring to in your last sentence? Does this happen with smaller images say 200kb or 150x150? Keep in mind this isn't a support forum but a WP development question answer site, questions here are about programming with WordPress, so your question may not be a good fit for the site, and you may get a programmer oriented answer that requires PHP knowledge, as well as coding oriented questions trying to understand your question

Comment: I automatically update all my plug-ins. Therefore I referred to all plug-ins that I have installed.
I tried to test this. But today it worked perfectly with large and small pictures. I did not change anything. And it did not work for more than a month now.
Oh, I did not know that this is only about WP development. Sorry.